# How to compile the project with .dsw File missing in Visual C++

Tags: visual-c++

I am a newbie in Vc++ , while trying to compile a project i am not able to locate a .dsw file , somehow im  in need to recreate a .dsw file so that i can compile the project , how to do this , whether i need to add all the files into a new workspace  and recreate it or any other way to achieve this.Kindly suggest a way to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DSW file extension is a workspace file, and it contains the workspace settings for the Microsoft Visual ++ development software.

If you missed this file then you should create new workspace and add the file in it.